# CSS ONLY: <div> that fills up <th> parent

Tags: html, css

[image]

I need the red div to fill up the parent with blue background.
http://jsfiddle.net/jiantongc/kyR8q/

Tried various fixes on `.rowlevel2-deco` but didn't work:
`height:100%;` `box-sizing: border-box;` etc.

*Similar problem: [Chrome doesn't honor row height if rowspan is present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15449185/chrome-doesnt-honor-row-height-if-rowspan-is-present) but w/o actual working solution.*

Answer (score 2):

```
.rowlevel2-deco{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Seems to work. http://jsfiddle.net/kyR8q/27/ Also, to vertically center it use:

```
.rowlevel2-deco:before {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: Looks like the `outer` label should be vertically centered (as the OP wants), to achieve such a thing, we need to tweak it a little more with `:before` pseudo-element, here is the full fiddle as for reference http://jsfiddle.net/kyR8q/10/

Comment: @Jian Oh god… Neither does allcaps' answer… Ugh.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `height="1"` to the `th`:

```
<th rowspan="2" class="rowlevel2" height="1">
```

Than there is a small padding, get rid of it by adding `padding:0;`:

```
.rowlevel2 {
     background: blue; /* don't want to see blue */
     padding: 0;    
 }
```

### UPDATE Chrome and FireFox

Short: explicitly specify height for all parent elements that get their height from content height and don't have a height explicitly defined.

Long: [This](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#the-height-property), [this](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=295717) made me think it was impossible. But [this test](https://bug295717.bugzilla.mozilla.org/attachment.cgi?id=204786) works in FF and not in Chrome. This code works in both:

```
* { padding:0; } /* All paddings be gone! This is not a padding problem */

table { height: 1px; } /* FF needs a height */

.foo {
    background: blue; /* Don't want to see blue */
    height: 100%; /* FF needs a height agian */
}

.bar {
    background: red;
    height:100%;
    width: 100px;
    display:inline-block; /* Chrome needs inline-block, FF doesn't care. */
}

.bar:before {
    content:'';
    display:inline-block;
    height:100%;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

.ni {
    background: gray;
    width:120px;
    height:40px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="2" class="foo">
                <div class="bar">Bar</div>
            </th>
            <th>
                <div class="ni">Knight 1</div>
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <div class="ni">Knight 2</div>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/allcaps/V7jzL/2/

And it works also with [your class names](http://jsfiddle.net/allcaps/kyR8q/37/) ;).

> `<percentage>` Specifies a percentage height. The percentage is
>   calculated with respect to the height of the generated box's
>   containing block. If the height of the containing block is not
>   specified explicitly (i.e., it depends on content height), and this
>   element is not absolutely positioned, the value computes to 'auto'.

The table height depends on content height == auto. Therefore Mozilla wants the height explicitly defined on parent elements. `table { height: 1px; }` and `.foo { height: 100%; } does that.`1px;` is a value smaller than any normal table and the content height takes precedence anyway. Pushes the table to the right size.

Thanks to @bjb568 for the `display:inline-block;`.
Thanks to @KingKing for `.bar:before { content:''; ... }`.

Comment: Don't know :D. Stuck in the back of my brain. http://jsfiddle.net/allcaps/kyR8q/6/

Comment: @bjb568: I think your answer is right (upvoted) and not a hack like mine :P

Comment: @bjb568 and @Jian: I found how this works. You need to set explicit height on all parent elements that get their height from the content. So `table { height:1px; }` and `.rowlevel2 { height:100%; }`. See the update.

Comment: Oh. This answer seems to be better now.

Comment: @allcaps just found out that this does't really work on IE8 (perhaps all IEs)

Comment: It can't be done: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5998500/ie8-stretching-table-cell-height You have to workaround and present the next best thing. `<!--[if IE 8]>Stylesheet for IE 8 here.<![endif]-->`

Answer (score 0):

100% height will work on absolute positioned elements. So CSS will be:

```
th.rowlevel2{
    background: blue; /* don't want to see blue */
    width: 100px;
    position: relative;
}

.rowlevel2-deco{
    background: red;
    height:100%;
    width: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
```

But in this case parent must have defined width.

http://jsfiddle.net/aLQh7/1/

Comment: If you're using `position: absolute` for anything besides removing from flow, you're doing it wrong (or so they say).

Answer (score -1):

Why not use jQuery?

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('.rowlevel2-deco').
      css({
        'width': $('.rowlevel2').width(),
        'height': $('.rowlevel2').height()  
    });
});
```

Vertically align in red div:

```
.rowlevel2-deco {
    background: red;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

[View it here](http://jsfiddle.net/6wDu3/)

Comment: "Any reason not to use JavaScript?" Because this is a CSS question? …

Comment: Why downvote? Usually, web coding has a task to solve and mostly the task is not "using CSS" but getting something to do something, in the most semantic and effective way. Semantically, tables are meant for displaying tabular data. Anything "deco" that needs to "stretch to fit with the tabular data" arguably belongs with JavaScript.

Comment: No. Styles belong in stylesheets.

Comment: @niennte I understand your point, but if I could use js I would use it, I'm rendering a million table cells and performance issue is one of the key reasons. That's why I made it clear at the title :)